# XML reader seems to ignore tag hierarchy

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

In an XML file, I'm trying to get the content of a tag that appears multiple times at different levels in the tag hierarchy. I'm trying to get the content of the highest level occurrence of the tag, but my XML reader (BeautifulSoup for Python) keeps giving me the wrong content.

Here is the concrete problem. This is part of the XML file (condensed to the parts I believe are relevant):

```
<object>
    <name>person</name>
    <part>
        <name>head</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>337</xmin>
            <ymin>2</ymin>
            <xmax>382</xmax>
            <ymax>66</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </part>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>334</xmin>
        <ymin>1</ymin>
        <xmax>436</xmax>
        <ymax>373</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

I'm interested in getting the content of the `<bndbox>` tag at the very end of this snippet via the command

```
box = object.bndbox
```

But if I print out `box`, I keep getting this:

```
<bndbox>
    <xmin>337</xmin>
    <ymin>2</ymin>
    <xmax>382</xmax>
    <ymax>66</ymax>
</bndbox>
```

This makes no sense to me. The box above that I keep getting is one hierarchy level lower than what I'm asking for, under a `<part>` tag, so I should only be able to access this box via

```
object.part.bndbox
```

while

```
object.bndbox
```

should give me the only box that is hierarchically directly under the `object` tag, which is the last box in the snippet above.

Comment: `object` is a python built-in class name.  I wonder if that is causing the issue?

Comment: BeautifulSoup returns the first tag matching that name, so `object.bbox` refers to the first bbox in the XML, regardless of position in the hierarchy.

Comment: @mjsqu so how do I ignore the first box and get the second instead?

Comment: Try this: `[t for t in object.contents if t.name == 'bndbox']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [@mjsqu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3388954/mjsqu) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971317/xml-reader-seems-to-ignore-tag-hierarchy#comment86958670_49971317):

> BeautifulSoup returns the first tag matching that name, so object.bbox refers to the first bbox in the XML, regardless of position in the hierarchy.

So, to get the *second* `<bndbox>` tag, or, the `<bndbox>` which is the direct child of the `<object>` tag, you can use `recursive=False` as a parameter. This will look only for the tags that are direct children of the current tag.

```
xml = '''
<object>
    <name>person</name>
    <part>
        <name>head</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>337</xmin>
            <ymin>2</ymin>
            <xmax>382</xmax>
            <ymax>66</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </part>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>334</xmin>
        <ymin>1</ymin>
        <xmax>436</xmax>
        <ymax>373</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
print(soup.object.find('bndbox', recursive=False))
```

Output:

```
<bndbox>
<xmin>334</xmin>
<ymin>1</ymin>
<xmax>436</xmax>
<ymax>373</ymax>
</bndbox>
```

Comment: That's exactly right! Thank you! Not sure how I feel about the fact that navigating by tags gets you the first appearance of the tag. This being the default behavior defeats the whole purpose of why to use XML in the first place, namely that it is a hierarchical format.

Answer (score 1):

**Going down the Tree**

*Suggestion*, please review quickly the Official BeautifulSoup Documentation [**HERE**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '''<object>
    <name>person</name>
    <part>
        <name>head</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>337</xmin>
            <ymin>2</ymin>
            <xmax>382</xmax>
            <ymax>66</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </part>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>334</xmin>
        <ymin>1</ymin>
        <xmax>436</xmax>
        <ymax>373</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')

print(soup.find('name'))  # or
# only string > print(soup.find('name').text)

print(soup.part.bndbox.xmin)  # we traverse through the tree >part>bndbox>xmin

print(soup.xmin)
```

Will return the same because it gives back the first occurrence of the **tag**

```
print(soup.find('xmin')) # is the same as soup.xmin
```

To find **multiple** same tag, *specifically the second one*:

```
bnxboxes = soup.find_all('bndbox') #
# we can either iterate through it or
print(bnxboxes[1]) # the Second occurence of tag (computer counting 0,1,2..)
```

We can also **Go up the Tree**

> Continuing the “family tree” analogy, every tag and every string has a parent: the tag that contains it.

```
the_xmin_tag = soup.xmin # we find the xmin tag
print(the_xmin_tag.parent)
```

We can also **Go sideways**

```
using `.next_sibling` and `.previous_sibling`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I don't generally know the index number of the occurrence I want upfront, I only know that it is the top-level occurrence, so doing `find_all()` and then indexing the resulting list doesn't help in my case. Keyur's suggestion solved my problem.

Comment: Of course Alex, it's a use of the method. However, I just wanted you to know how to traverse through the tree, using `recursive = False` won't be very applicable in larger cases. If you do appreciate (think it's an alternative correct answer ) give it an upvote so it's noticed.