# beautiful soup parse url from messy output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have beautiful soup code that looks like:

```
 for item in beautifulSoupObj.find_all('cite'):
            pagelink.append(item.get_text())
```

the problem is, the html code I'm trying to parse looks like:

```
<cite>https://www.<strong>websiteurl.com/id=6</strong></cite>
```

My current selector above would get everything, including `strong` tags in it.

Thus, how can I parse only:

```
https://www.websiteurl.com/id=6
```

Note `<cite>` appears multiple times throughout the page, and I want to extract, and print everything.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that using `.get_text()` is giving you `https://www.<strong>websiteurl.com/id=6</strong>`? For me, it's returning `https://www.websiteurl.com/id=6`.

Comment: it's ok (`.get_text()`)

Comment: @KeyurPotdar - no that is what the source of the page has. That was an example of what I'm trying to parse. so `.get_text()` would extract only `https://www.websiteurl.com/id=6` from source code of `<cite>https://www.<strong>websiteurl.com/id=6</strong></cite>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting only the text portion is easy as doing `.text` on the object.
We can use basic **BeautifulSoup** methods to traverse the tree hierarchy.

Helpful explanation on how to do that: [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49978612/6929467)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<cite>https://www.<strong>websiteurl.com/id=6</strong></cite>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.cite.text)
# is the same as soup.find('cite').text
```